# Entity Framework - Using a lookup (picklist) table with a lookup key

Tags: sql, wpf, frameworks, entity

I'm working on a WPF application that is working well using the Entity Framework (3.5 SP1) for complicated table structures. The problem now is I want to get a list from the EF that includes lookups into a picklist table that has multiple picklists in it.

**In SQL I would write a sub select as such:**

SELECT Name, (Select typeName from PickLists where type_id = items.type_id and picklist_key=333) as Type_desc 
FROM Items

There are no Foreign keys for this, and the picklists table is never updated using the EF, so it is read only as far as the EF is concerned.

I'm not sure the best method to put this into the model if at all.

I'm displaying in a read-only datagrid on a dashboard.

Thanks!

Comment: I found a better way to implement this: use a value converter that does the lookup for me. Actually, I loaded the entire pick list table into a datatable for other pick list use and just filter it.
The trick is using a parameter on the value converter that filters the pick list to only valid values.